# MongoDB match aggregation stage with $expr and $in with Doctrine ODM

Tags: doctrine-odm

Documents in a pipeline stage have fields: string `company` and array `ancestors`, I need to filter out just the ones that have company mentioned in ancestors:

```
# input
{ company: 'A', ancestors: ['B', 'C'] }
{ company: 'X', ancestors: ['B', 'X'] }
{ company: 'A', ancestors: ['A', 'B'] }

# expected result
{ company: 'X', ancestors: ['B', 'X'] }
{ company: 'A', ancestors: ['A', 'B'] }
```

Aggregation pipeline I built in MongoDB Compass works as expected. Cannot find a way to translate one of the stages to a Doctrine ODM [Aggregation Builder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.5/reference/aggregation-builder.html) syntax. Problem stage has a type `$match`:

```
{
  $expr: {
    $in: [ "$company", '$ancestors' ]
  }
}
```

Tried `$ab->match()->expr()->in('$company', '$ancestors');` which fails this `->in()` is not an aggregation one, but a plain query "in" that expects a single array argument. Aggregation "in" derives from the aggregation builder itself `$ab->expr()->in(...)` inside some.. expr?

```
$ab->addAnd(
  $ab->expr()->in('$company', '$ancestors')
)
```

Not exactply the logic I am after, `addAnd()` also requires more expressions.

What syntax of the Doctrine aggregation builder would create the aggregatiop stage?